# Class with collection of itself ORMLite

Tags: android, one-to-many, ormlite

How can i create one-to-many relation with the table itself in ormlite?  I have a class that holds collection of itself.  I don't know how to map this class.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "USER")
public class User {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String username;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<User> friends;
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a class that holds collection of itself. I don't know how to map this class.

I think the best way would be to define a `UserFriend` entity that has a reference to the owner `User`, friend `User`, and an id.   Something like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "USERFRIEND")
public class UserFriend {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;
    // corresponds to the user who has the friend
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private User user;
    // corresponds to the friend of the user
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private User friend;
    ...
```

Then your foreign collection becomes:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(foreignFieldName = 'user')
private ForeignCollection<UserFriend> friends;
```

Notice the `foreignFieldName` which has to point to the `user` so the user's friends can be found.

Comment: Thank you.You have helped me a lot.